# Download RPMs for an offline RHEL from a networked Debian box

Tags: linux, debian, rpm, rhel

I have two computers at work, a Kali (Debian) box with network access and a disc burner and a RHEL 7 box with a disc drive on a sneakernet. I absolutely cannot connect the RHEL 7 box to the internet.

I am trying to download the RPMs I need, with all dependencies, on the Kali box to bring to the RHEL box.

On RHEL I would use yum, and if I had another RHEL box on the network I could use yum and download only. But I don't know what to do since the networked computer is Debian.

Comment: There is a package `yum` on Debian too.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this, but when I try to add repos to yum `sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm` I get the error `Requires: redhat-release >= 7`. If I add --skip-broken then it just skips over the repo without adding it.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL requires a client certificate to connect to Red Hat's repositories. Two-sided TLS is used by RHEL and I don't think you can create a local mirror on a different distribution. I think it may be better to have a VM on the Kali box to provide RHEL RPMs to your other hosts.